# Draw an arc between two points with radius in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I need to draw an arc with R radius between two points x1,y1 and x2,y2. I'm trying to draw this arc on html canvas. I'll add two examples along with this question.

[Examples, what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdCWM.jpg)

Comment: Hello @trojancode : welcome to SO – please provide a minimal example of what you have tried yourself to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have  point x1,y1 ,  x2,y2 and radius i need to draw an arc between these two points with radius R

Comment: If using pixi, the arcTo function is exactly what you need http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#arcTo

Comment: I know. but pixi arcTo needs a tangent point. but i need zrc between two points

Answer (score 0):

You can render arc like:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
ctx.stroke();
```

Params 100/100 - arc center, 50 - radius.

If you want to render between 2 dots - you need to find center dot(like centerX = x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2).

More you can read here and find some examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc